# Linux root filesystem on custom hardware

Tags: boot, memory, filesystems, linux-kernel

I have a custom-designed SoC implemented on FPGA, based on an ARM-processor clone, on which I am trying to boot Linux (kernel 3.10).

I have successfully added support to my custom peripherals (an USART, Interrupt Controller and Timer), allowing me to see the printk messages displayed by the kernel up to the point of trying to mount root filesystem.

I have a 2GB custom non-volatile memory, random-access, read write, mapped from address 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF from which the bootloader executes, and which contains the kernel and the filesystem partition. The bootloader copies kernel to RAM (256Mb, from 0x80000000 to 0x8FFFFFFF) and then passes control to Linux, which fails at the point: "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)".

From my debugging and internet searches, it seems the kernel cannot recognize my non-volatile memory, therefore cannot mount the filesystem.

How do I tell the kernel that it should boot from that memory, and which code must be added to the kernel? For example, would it be possible to make the kernel think my memory is a Nand, and modify Nand drivers to access it correctly?

Thank you in advance for all help and sugestions.

Comment: You are being vague about this *"2GB custom non-volatile memory"*.  You need to study **MTD** and **UBI**, and then develop a device driver for either susbsystem.  Assuming you need wear-leveling, then a simple block device, RAM-disk emulation is not sufficient, and you need to use at least MTD.  If bad-block management and error correction are necessary like NAND flash, then you need to use UBI.  Once you have a block device defined for this NV memory, then you can create a filesystem on top of it, and designate it as the rootfs in the command line.

Comment: Sawdust, thank you for your reply. MTD and UBI are not necessary in this case, since the memory is addressable at byte, halfword and word granularities (for all intents and purposes, it works like a RAM) and requires no wear-leveling at all. I can define it as a RAM in my DTB, and in that case Linux can access it perfectly, but then it uses it as RAM memory, which is not what I need.

Comment: Then you need to pick out what you need from my comment. You need to write a device driver for "a simple **block device**, such as a RAM-disk."  "Once you have a **block device** defined for this NV memory, then you can create a filesystem on top of it, and designate it as the rootfs in the command line."  BTW "granularity" is not the reason for using MTD or UBI.  SPI NOR flash is byte addressable.  If an erase operation is required for writing then you need MTD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing now for your "filesystem partition."  But you can place an initrd into your nonvolatile storage that looks/acts like RAM, and then have your bootloader tell Linux to use the initrd.

Most initrds do some setup and then try to re-mount a root filesystem on a block device.  In your case, your initrd would be your real root filesystem and you'd need to be placing utilities like shells, etc. in the initrd.

When booting on ARM using U-Boot, basically the boot commands load the kernel and initrd from a storage device into a fixed RAM location, and then the address of the initrd is passed to the kernel as a command line parameter, specifying the address.

---

Well, the MTD driver can take a section of RAM (there's a "Physical System RAM" option in the MTD driver on `make menuconfig`) and turn it into a block device, if you really need a readable/writeable block device.  It can be used to mount graphics card RAM as a small swap partition, for example.  [See this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gpu_newbies/eVhc6p0hyVo/0xhRDAU3rGIJ).

I think the command to do it would be `modprobe phram phram=0x00100000;256MiB`, if you have a 256MByte filesystem at memory location 0x00100000.  Then `modprobe mtdblock` which then makes `/dev/mtdblock0`.  You can then do things like `mount /dev/mtdblock0` and such.  So you'd need a small script in an initrd that does the above, then `fsck /dev/mtdblock0`, and then starts your `init` or whatever your process 1 is.

You might even be able to specify that all on the kernel command line somehow but I'm not sure if that's supported.  You might want to use a small initrd anyway just to be flexible.

Comment: Ultrasawblade, than you for your reply. This solution works, and is what I'm using for now, but unfortunately it won't suffice as the project develops. I need Linux to understand my memory as something other than RAM, which is why I mentioned telling Linux it is something else, then modifying the appropriate drivers. For example,  if I could make Linux think it is the first hard-drive, it would suit my needs. I know I'm asking for something too specific, apologies; unfortunately it's a hardware development project with very specific needs and I lack the necessary Linux expertise for it.

Comment: I've updated with edits.